# Blender Animations: Armature Parenting Resulting in Odd Transformations and Multiple Animations

Tags: action, blender, mesh

I apologize if I do this incorrectly, first time posting.

Here's a git repo containing the file:
https://github.com/caydenbullock/StoneCreature

[image: enticing image of mesh]

I'm working on a monster in blender, and I'm having problems with transformations and the creation of animations. I've made them before, although never from a hand made armature, let alone an armature of armatures parented to each other (which i anticipate is a source of my problems).

Hear me out on my workflow and I think this will be enough to identify where I've gone wrong:

I parented armatures to a rig via this workflow:

- Create mesh in individual components (arms, body, head)
- Hide all but one component (ig: body first)
- Give it the appropriate bones (in my case a single spine bone) and parent with automatic weights
- Hide the component, unhide the next component (Arms)
- Create bones (upper arm, forearm, hands, fingers) and apply weights
- Continue until all components of the mesh have appropriate bone structures
- The final (and probably incorrect step) I parented all individual component source bones to the original spine bone, so that they would move with it
  -eg: hand bones parented to arm bone parented to spine bone

I understand that what I have is done is wrong because there are a few key problems:

- Trying to make an animation in the Action Editor creates an animation for each individual armature acting as a child to the singular "spine" parent. I assume this is because i have a bunch of armatures instead of somehow making them all into one.
- Moving on from one animation to another, saving, checking the fake user button, making sure to copy, delete keyframes, save, etc... regardless of my efforts, results in the prior animation getting completely destroyed/overwritten by the following keyframes.
- In pose mode, transforming the spine bone everything is parented to has unexpected effects on some of the bones in the stomach (labeled body in the included file)

Please do not kill me for my naming system, for it does not exist:

[image: a blender hirearchy]

I am sorry for the mess I've made here. I thought I was ready.... I am, of course, prepared and willing to re-rig this entire mess once over again.